# Use json in typescript with ionic

Tags: json, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using typescript and I'm trying to declare a variable with the data from my json file. I already made some interfaces using [js2ts.com](http://json2ts.com). But I don't know how to call the json file in my typescript file.

Comment: What version of Ionic? What's your build system? Is the json file a known artifact at build time, or is it an unknown file loaded dynamically at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a json file/structure, you're going to need to make an AJAX call to it like it was a server resource. If it's an object within a module/library, you can import the object. I'm assuming this is a web app, since you mentioned ionic. If it were a NodeJS app, you could load the resource using the `fs` module.

Some flavor of the following should work:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/PATH_TO_JSON'
}).then(function success(response) {
    // Success handling
}, function failure(response) {
   // Error handling
 });
```

If you are attempting to access the file when it is on the device, look into the [Cordova File API](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html).

Comment: The json file is a local file so I assume I can just import it? How can I do that? Really appreciate you helping me!!

Comment: Local to what? The application (on the server) or the client? I'm assuming it's on the server, so your app can AJAX to it. Or is this a configuration file for the Ionic app that your attempting to store with the client app on the device?

Comment: I'm trying things out so the json file is stored with the client app yes.

Comment: Stored as a file with the app or with localStorage in the browser?

Comment: Check out the Cordova File API if you haven't already. I've added a link to my answer.

Comment: So I have 2 files in the same folder in my project, one named data.ts and the other datainfo.json. So stored as a file with the app I guess.

Comment: You're probably going to have to use the File API I mentioned if that file is stored with the device during install. If you have a web service backend where this file can reside, you could always make an AJAX call to it and then use localStorage to cache it on the device.